# How to add custom metadata for Kentor idprovider?

Tags: c#, client, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

I'm using **Kentor.AuthService.Idp** project as a starting point.

The SAML enabled service provider I am attempting to single sign on to requires the following attributes be part of the metadata file:

*login-id, partner-id, platform, user-email*

**How do I add these to an existing metadata or create a new metadata that includes these?**

The service provider documentation specifically states:

> the list of attributes must be contained in the metadata file and in the assertions you generate

**Does including these attributes in the metadata fulfill the service provider requirement, or is including these attributes in the assertion an entirely different task than including them in the metadata?**

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different things.

Looks like they want you to specify a list of supported attributes ni the metadata. The System.IdentityModel metadata classes used by AuthServices supports that, but you'll had to add them in yourself.

Adding the attributes on the generated assertions is a different task. You can do that by adding them as claims on the identity that you use for creating the assertion.

Comment: I attempted to answer my own question with code samples. Can you take a look? I'm not certain if I interpreted your answer correctly. I'm also not certain how to form an sso auth post using the descriptor and claims. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Anders answer, I came up with the following code.

**Metadata Supported Attributes**

```
var descriptor = new IdentityProviderSingleSignOnDescriptor();
descriptor.SupportedAttributes.Add(new Saml2Attribute("platform", "desktop"));
descriptor.SupportedAttributes.Add(new Saml2Attribute("partnerid", "partner123"));
descriptor.SupportedAttributes.Add(new Saml2Attribute("login-id", "user9"));
descriptor.SupportedAttributes.Add(new Saml2Attribute("useremail", "donotreply@domain.com"));
```

**Attributes on generated assertions**

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim("platform", "desktop"));
claims.Add(new Claim("partnerid", "partner123"));
claims.Add(new Claim("login-id", "user9"));
claims.Add(new Claim("useremail", "noreply@domain.com"));
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
```

I'm not certain how to add the claims to an assertion.